# laravel - append html code from database into a page

Tags: ajax, laravel

I will try to keep it simple in database I have 2 fields, name = name of site and html = html code of that site.

Database looks like this:

```
UPDATE `websites` SET `name` = 'name', `html` = ' <title>Template 1</title> <link href="http://localhost/templates/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <div class="logo"> <img class="images" id="image" src="#" alt="Your Logo"> </div> <div contenteditable="true" id="content" class="draggable ui-widget-content refresh ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative; left: 209px; top: 139px;"><p>Change Text inside this box</p></div> <div id="editTxt" class="refresh" contenteditable="true"> <p>This text can be by the user.</p> </div> ' WHERE `websites`.`id` = 1;
```

Now when I type into browser localhost/website/{name} I would like to append html code from that database into a browser using ajax.

I have started something like this:

Controller:

```
function websites($name)
    {
        $websites = Website::all();
        return view('layouts/website', ['websites' => $websites]);
        $name = $websites->name;
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('website/{name}', 'BuilderController@websites');
```

website.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master') @section('title', 'Website Builder') @section('content')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<div class="container template_class ">
    @foreach ($websites as $website)
    <a class="content-link" href="{{ asset($website->name )}}">
        <img src="{{ asset($website->html )}}"/>
        </a> @endforeach

</div>
</body>
<link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link  href="{{asset ('//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js') !!}">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/bootstrap-formhelpers.js') !!}">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/template.js') !!}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js') !!}">
</script>

</html>
@endsection @show
```

Can anyone help me get started?

Comment: I don't quite understand this `<img src="{{ asset($website->html )}}"/>`. Isn't `$website->html` full of html-code?

Comment: It is, I am working on it all the time trying to fix it, how would I just display that html code from database? Even better without much code in blade.php so it just displays html from the database?

Answer (score 1):

You're wanting to [Displaying Unescaped Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data):

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want
>   your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
{!! $website->html !!}
```

Comment: I still get this error Method App\Http\Controllers\BuilderController::websites() does not exist

Comment: That means that Laravel can't find your `websites` function in `BuilderController`. That's a completely different issue.

Comment: but question is why cannot laravel find it, it is there